# Can't import Eclipse project set with EGit projects

Tags: eclipse, git

I have a few projects in the company Git server and I wanted to create a few project sets so that creating a new workspace for a specific project would be just importing the needed project set.

When trying to import it to a blan workspace, I get this error:

```
The following errors occurred while importing projects. Some projects may not be loaded.
  mycompanyserver.com
  mycompanyserver.com
```

All of the URLs are https and I have EGit and JGit installed, not sure what's happening. Do I need to add valid Git credentials to access that?

**EDIT**

just realised that the server was down, now the error is:

```
The following errors occurred while importing projects. Some projects may not be loaded.
  unable to find valid certification path to requested target
  unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Does connecting to those https URLs with a web browser throw up SSL certificate warnings?

Comment: no, but it redirects me to the login page if I'm not authenticated. how can I cross this with eclipse?

Comment: Did you make an ssh key pair for you, one on the host, one in /home/username/.ssh?

Comment: Got it now, never realised that we had to put SSH keys in the server and in the local .ssh directory and add the key in Window -> Preferences -> SSH. All working now, can you put it as an answer?

Comment: Any idea why, when importing a project set with git URLs, it uses the local git that I already had instead of cloning a new one? That's the behaviour I want, but I'm just curious on how EGit does it.